# How does elasticsearch multi search work?

Tags: elasticsearch

How does it work in the background?
Lets say it has two queries.
Would the total time taken be

**1) network latency + time for query1 + time for query2**

or

**2) network latency + max(time for query1, time for query2)**

I am assuming its the later but couldn't find any documentation to confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total time is the network latency and the slowest of the searches, as can be seen in the implementation of [TransportMultiSearchAction](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/TransportMultiSearchAction.java#L55).

Note that searches can be routed to other nodes in the cluster, and network latency is of course a factor then as well. See the [preference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html) search parameter to control that.